# Shared folder doesn't work from windows 10 machines to windows server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2012, domain, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

I have a problem with 4 of my servers actually I can't access the shared folders of these servers from my clients they are all windows 10 and fully updated. The same folders I can access them from one server to another with the same username as the windows 10 machines. I have tried and researched a lot but can't find a solution. Had someone this problem before if yes how did they resolve it? please don't say reinstall windows don't work and I can't remove the server from the network.

Comment: What error message are you getting or what indicates to you that it is not working exactly. You try to go to `\\server\share` and press enter from the Windows 10 machine and then what happens? Provide more detail for more accurate suggestions or help.

Comment: Windows cannot access \\server  
Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose. 
Error code: 0x80070035
The network path was not found.

Comment: Okay, so what is the IP address of one of the clients with an issue and the subnet mask, and the same for the IP and subnet mask of one of the servers you have trouble accessing the share from the Win 10 client? Perhaps the client network and the server network are on different subnets and you need to allow the networks to route or allow SMB traffic to/from since it works from server-to-server. Also, are the clients with the problem on Wi-Fi network rather than Ethernet hard wired where Wi-Fi isolation settings may be an issue or Windows FW NIC trust profile zones or scope may need defined?

Comment: I have tried everything they are on the same subnet and same network I can access other servers only this 4 and this happened since I had a virus wanamine virus and I removed it but I still have the shared problem on 4 of the servers and one of them is SQL server and the other Mail server so I can't remove them and read them or play with them.